# How can I set up a metered subscription on Stripe that bills yearly but charges for overage monthly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

So basically I am trying to set up a subscription on stripe where I have a plan that allows 5000 monthly credits and bills a flat $299 yearly. I want to charge customers who exceed their monthly credit usage by the end of every month.

Suppose a customer uses 100 additional credits, I want to bill $0.07 for each additional credit, so by the end of the month, I want to bill them an additional $7.

One idea comes to mind which is to use a combo of a standard pricing model with the $299 charged yearly and a graduated pricing model that charges $0 up to 5000 credits and then charges $0.07 for every credit. But I would need the customer to subscribe to two products.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it with just one subscription.

You need to listen to the `invoice.created` event and manually add in the $299 price as an additional invoice item when the time is right (e.g., in every 12 cycles).